# QT QML import ListModel from C++ to QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

How can i change the model of a PathView with c++ code ?
i add an objectName to my pathView to find it, then i change the property like this, but when i do that, my list is empty :

```
QDeclarativeItem *listSynergie  = myClass.itemMain->findChild<QDeclarativeItem*> ("PathViewInscription");
listSynergie->setProperty("model", QVariant::fromValue(dataList));
```

My data list is fill like this :

```
QList<QObject*> dataList;
dataList.append(new synergieListObject("Item 1", "1",false));
dataList.append(new synergieListObject("Item 2", "2",true));
dataList.append(new synergieListObject("Item 3", "3",false));
dataList.append(new synergieListObject("Item 4", "4",false));
```

This is the code of my PathView :

```
PathView {
    objectName: "PathViewInscription"
    Keys.onRightPressed: if (!moving) { incrementCurrentIndex(); console.log(moving) }
    Keys.onLeftPressed: if (!moving) decrementCurrentIndex()
    id: view
    anchors.fill: parent
    highlight: Image { source: "../spinner_selecter.png"; width: view.width; height: itemHeight+4; opacity:0.3}
    preferredHighlightBegin: 0.5
    preferredHighlightEnd: 0.5
    focus: true
    model: appModel
    delegate: appDelegate

    dragMargin: view.width/2
    pathItemCount: height/itemHeight
    path: Path {
        startX: view.width/2; startY: -itemHeight/2
        PathLine { x: view.width/2; y: view.pathItemCount*itemHeight + itemHeight }
    }
}
```

and the code of ListModel :

```
ListModel {
    id: appModel
    ListElement { label: "syn1"; value: "1"; selected:false}
    ListElement { label: "syn2"; value: "2" ; selected:false}
    ListElement { label: "syn3"; value: "3" ; selected:false}
}
```

what's wrong ?
Thanks !

**EDIT :**

the code of the appDelegate :

```
    Component {
    id: appDelegate
    Item {
        width: 100; height: 100

        Text {
            anchors { horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter }
            text: label
            smooth: true
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: view.currentIndex = index
        }
    }
}
```

the code of my object :

```
    #ifndef SYNERGIELISTOBJECT_H
#define SYNERGIELISTOBJECT_H
#include <QObject>

class synergieListObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString label READ label WRITE setLabel NOTIFY labelChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString value READ value WRITE setValue NOTIFY valueChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool selected READ selected WRITE setSelected NOTIFY selectedChanged)

public:
    synergieListObject(QObject *parent=0);
    synergieListObject(const QString &label,const QString &value,bool selected, QObject *parent=0);

    QString label() const;
    void setLabel(const QString &label);

    QString value() const;
    void setValue(const QString &value);

    bool selected() const;
    void setSelected(const bool &selected);

signals:
    void labelChanged();
    void valueChanged();
    void selectedChanged();

private:
    QString m_label;
    QString m_value;
    bool m_selected;
};

#endif // SYNERGIELISTOBJECT_H
```

c++ my object :

```
#include "synergielistobject.h"


synergieListObject::synergieListObject(QObject *parent): QObject(parent)
{
}

synergieListObject::synergieListObject(const QString &label,const QString &value,bool selected, QObject *parent): QObject(parent), m_label(label), m_value(value), m_selected(selected)
{
}

QString synergieListObject::label() const
{
    return m_label;
}

void synergieListObject::setLabel(const QString &label)
{
    if (label != m_label) {
        m_label = label;
        emit labelChanged();
    }
}


QString synergieListObject::value() const
{
    return m_value;
}

void synergieListObject::setValue(const QString &value)
{
    if (value != m_value) {
        m_value = value;
        emit valueChanged();
    }
}


bool synergieListObject::selected() const
{
    return m_selected;
}

void synergieListObject::setSelected(const bool &selected)
{
    if (selected != m_selected) {
        m_selected = selected;
        emit selectedChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to post the 'data' function in SynergieListObject and the source for appDelegate.

Comment: I have never used QdeclarativeItem to set model in QML . Try this instead `QDeclarativeContext *ctxt = view.rootContext();
     ctxt->setContextProperty("model", QVariant::fromValue(dataList));`

Comment: Thanks, my PathView is not on root View, how to find the good child to change the context property ?

Comment: Declare the model as a property of the root. This way you can set model.Or add a function that takes model as argument and sets the model for the view. Then you can call this function from c++.

Comment: i add a function : function setModel(myModel){
  view.model=myModel
  return "some return value"
}
and i call it like this :
    QObject *lSynergie = myClass.itemMain->findChild<QObject*>("PathViewInscription");
   QVariant returnedValue;
   QMetaObject::invokeMethod(lSynergie, "setModel",
           Q_RETURN_ARG(QVariant, returnedValue),
           Q_ARG(QVariant, QVariant::fromValue(dataList)));
 qDebug() << "QML function returned:" << returnedValue.toString();

and for my 4 object i try to add, i've this 4 error : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: label

we are near!thanks!

Comment: i add  text: modelData.label and it works! can you make a anwser and i valid it.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never used QdeclarativeItem to set model in QML . Try this instead

```
QDeclarativeContext *ctxt = view.rootContext(); ctxt->setContextProperty("model",  QVariant::fromValue(dataList));
```

Declare the model as a property of the root. This way you can set model.Or add a function that takes model as argument and sets the model for the view. Then you can call this function from c++.